# Can Signalr execute client side functions when the browser is minimised or running in the background?

Tags: javascript, c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I have got the following code which will create a notification for a user when the browser is open:

**Server-side:**

```cs
[HubName("notificationhub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections =
        new ConnectionMapping<string>();

    public void SendNewNotification()
    {
        string notification_text = "This is a test notification";
        Clients.All.triggerNotification(notification_text);
    }
}
```

**Client side:**

```js
var notification_hub;

$(function () {
    notification_hub = $.connection.notificationhub;
    $.connection.hub.start();

    notification_hub.client.triggerNotification = function (message) {

        var notification = new Notification('Test notification', {
            body: message,
            icon: "~/content/img/favicon/favicon.ico",
            vibrate: [200, 100, 200],
        });
}
```

This works as expected when the browser is currently on screen. However, I also want this same piece of client-side code to execute if the user has minimised the browser (or running it in the background if it is a mobile device). The intended effect would be to have the 'push' notification generated for the user. At the moment, however, this is not the case.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: what you need is called "Service Worker"

Comment: @vasily.sib i am aware of service workers. Can you suggest a tutorial or example of them working alongside signalr and .net mvc?